# Why wont this simple C program print?

Tags: c, printing

I'm trying to make a basic C program to read from a file, but for some reason when I run it with `make Test1` and then .`/Test1 test1.txt` I get "error: 's' may be used uninitialized in this function".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {


    if (argc < 2) {
        printf("error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    FILE *fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (fp == NULL)  {
        printf ("error\n");
        return 0;
    }

    char * s;

    int r = fscanf(fp, "%s", s);

    while (r != EOF) {
        printf("%s\n", s);
        r = fscanf(fp, "%s", s);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do you start your program after you compile it?

Comment: Try add breakpoint and debug.

Comment: char * s isn't pointing to anything right now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with fscanf. It won't allocate any memory, you have to do this by yourself, e.g. by doing

```
char *s = malloc(100);  //array s is stored in the heap memory
```

or

```
char s[100];  //array s is stored in the stack
```

To make sure that fscanf won't read more than 100 characters (because that's how much memory we got) you have to write

```
int r = fscanf(fp, "%99s", s);
```

Comment: You had to leave one character for the null terminator, so `fscanf(fp, "%99s", s)`.

Comment: [Don't cast the return of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score 0):

It should be crashing as you are reading into s which is set to NULL, meaning there is no memory you have set aside to read into and it should crash your program, depending on OS depends on error

doing   `char s[1000]` at least gives it some memory to read into.

Comment: Yeah I was still testing code when I uploaded it. Removed the NULL, but I still get told that "s may be uninitialized".

Comment: @AlanGhalan, `s` IS uninitialized. You need to initialize it.

Comment: @lurker for some reason the OP changed the code, if you check the history it was assigned NULL

Comment: @lurker As it appears it was, and the OP changed it. Read [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48654448/why-wont-this-simple-c-program-print#comment84307136_48654473).

Comment: I see, thanks. I was a little late to the party.